# Webpack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, webpack, build, npm-build

I am fairly new to using webpack in webapps. I am trying to build the vue js and asp.net core SPA using nodejs and webpack. I am facing this error in the screenshot. I have installed the all the dependencies using npm then I tried to run .net core vue app it opens the cshtml web page but dependencies part of the web page are not loaded. Refer another screenshot.

[webpack command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBPCY.png)

[cshtml web page without any css and vue code loaded and is not compiled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks5RO.png)

[Devdependencies from Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzdjl.png)

[This Build command gives error in screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z3c5.png)

Please let me know if more details are required. I will appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Links to images can fail, and search engines cannot index that information. Make sure any textual information is in text form. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example demonstrating your problem will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

'm posting this here, it might help, i searched my issue on google, and found this thread.

in my case, i have a custom " optin " arg, that i'm using to optin features that are not included in the base build by default. I'm doing that because i have multiple entries and multiple outputs in the same project, and some entries are not always necessary, so i let the user optin for it.

Everything worked fine, but one day i misspelled it and wrote : npm run build.prod -- -optin=myfeature and i got this error, because it was missing one " - " before the optin argument.

So it was the -o argument that was enabled instead, and it was messing up with webpack outputs

Comment: whenever I run webpack command I get this error.D:\workspace\raas>webpack
[webpack-cli] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined